# Авторизация через nodejs(axios) passport.yandex.ru

Tags: авторизация, yandex-maps-jsapi, axios, яндекс-карты

Никто случаем не делал авторизацию на passport.yandex.ru через nodejs (axios)? У меня возникает проблема при отправке запроса https://passport.yandex.ru/registration-validations/auth/additional_data/ask_v2. 
Выдает ошибку 403 Forbidden.
Cookie все отправляю идентичные как и в браузере, то есть uniqueuid и Session_id
содержатся, только не пойму где ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего яндекс блокирует тебя по рефереру. Мало того что надо повторить все то что у тебя в браузере еще надо отправить данные с разрешенного хоста. Яндекс воспринимает это как атаку и попытку брутфорса. CORS соответственно не включен.

Чтобы работать с авторизацией используй официальное API - https://yandex.ru/dev/passport/

Comment: Весь прикол в том что, я сделал это, но напортачил в папке с проектом, теперь пытаюсь все заново написать и не получается.

Comment: А в чем смысл городить все это когда есть API от Яндекса где надо просто подставить ключ/сертификат для доступа? Самая элементарная причина это изменение логики или еще чего в работе и все что Вы написали перестанет работать.
Тем более в Гите скорее всего найдутся реализация под Ваш стек технологий, клонируй, поменяй ключи и пользуйся. Не надо придумывать велосипеды. Зачем столько времени тратить на реализацию?

Comment: У Яндекса есть сервис Яндекс.Дзен. И я не думаю что там можно использовать API от Яндекса, так как сервис запрещает создание и использование каких-либо API для упрощения или автоматизации.

Comment: Я решил проблему cookies с помощью использования модуля cookie-jar. Он собирает все использованные cookie в одну переменную, что избавляет от  самостоятельного копирования cookie в запрос.